# jquery adjust div when hover on another div

Tags: jquery, html, slidetoggle, jquery-hover

I have a handful of img icons that link to various external sites (email, facebook, twitter, etc) onclick, and I'm trying to have them show some hidden text in another `div` on hover.

The second fiddle link in [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17878391/make-a-div-css-change-when-hover-an-other-div) accomplishes something similar to what I want to do with CSS, however I'm trying to animate the show/hide using jQuery `slideToggle()`, which I've already implemented in other parts of the page, so css won't do.

[This thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4411511/change-div-property-when-hovering-on-another-div) seems like it has what I'm looking for, but I've used it as a template and nothing's working so far and I'm stumped. Here's my code, any suggestions would be much appreciated:

```
    $('div.tooltip').hide();
$('img.tooltip').hover(function() {

    which = $(this).attr("class");
    selector = 'div.' + which;
    slide = $(selector).slideToggle();
    console.log(slide);
});
```

p.s. - I thought maybe the problem was that when I call `slideToggle()` it doesn't undo the `hide()` call on line 1, but when I commented out that call and instead changed something simple like the font color, still no dice.

edit: for clarification, the `img` and its corresponding `div` share identical classnames (eg `img.tooltip email` should trigger `div.tooltip email`, etc), which is why I'm using "which" and "selector".

Comment: create a fiddle please

Comment: Do the img element have any other classes? If it does your the value of `selector` would look like: `"div.tooltip otherClass andAnotherone andSoOn"`. That would not be a valid jQuery selector, but it's hard to know without seeing the markup.

Answer (score 2):

Your problem is more than likely with the line `which = $(this).attr("class");` which will return a space separated list of all the classes that the element has. Since the image has at least `.tooltip` that means `selector` will look something like `div.tooltip someotherclass` which will look for a element of type `someotherclass` which is a descendant of a div with class tooltip. Since there will more than likely be no element type of `someotherclass` this will return nothing.

Edit:

If you are only using two classes like the case in your question you can change your code to

```
$('img.tooltip').hover(function() {
    which = $(this).attr("class").replace('tooltip', '').replace(' ','');
    selector = 'div.' + which;
    slide = $(selector).slideToggle();
    console.log(slide);
});
```

which will remove the `tooltip` class from the class string making `which = 'email'` rather than `which = 'tooltip email'`

Comment: Whoops, maybe I've just got a basic syntax error going on - I want the `img` to have **both** `tooltip` and `email/facebook/etc` classes, and hovering should `slideToggle` the `div` with the identical class name. Does separating the classes w/ a space not do that?

Comment: no because when you do `$(this).attr("class")` it will return a string that contains all the classes of that element in a space separated format. My answer doesnt get rid of the `tooltip` class off the element it just ignores it when looking for the class

Comment: OK - I don't understand why getting a space separated string would be bad, though, as long as I append that string to `'div.'` as I'm doing with the `selector`. This solution throws an error for me, it looks like it inserts a space in place of `tooltip` so the selector ends up being `div. email`. I've never made a fiddle before and I'm having trouble getting it to work properly but here's one, if it helps: http://jsfiddle.net/B5s56/

Comment: updated to remove spaces. The problem with having a space separated string is that you will end up with a selector of `div.tooltip email` which looks for a node of type email that is a descendant of a div with class tooltip. It will never find anything since there are no HTML nodes of type email.

Comment: Ah, there we go. Thanks so much for the help!

Answer (score 0):

Does

```
slide = $('div.tooltip').slideToggle();
```

not work?  I'm confused as to why you need the first two lines of that function.

Comment: This works, but it shows every tooltip, when I just want to show the one belonging to the icon which triggers the slideToggle. Think my problem has to do with the css nesting that @DGS is describing